# Weird results regarding structural break test in R

Tags: r, time-series, change-point

So I downloaded stock data and differenced it to get log returns. Im trying to split my dataset in a pre-covid and covid period so I try to detect my dataset for structural breaks. I fitted the Strucchange package and it results in a certain amount of breakpoints. The problem is one of the breaks is around 01-03-2020 which is actually after the crisis already started. If I look in my dataset the biggest swings are actually around a month before the indicated break. Anyone knows why this is?

Here is the code Im using:

```
Brazil = fread("IBOVESPA.csv", dec=",")
log_Bra <- diff(log(Brazil$Price))*100
ts = ts(log_Bra)
plot(ts)
y = breakpoints(ts~time(ts))
summary(y) 
coef(y)
```

I took a big dataset but to account for exogenous events I want to only use relevant data. I try to find a break at the start of covid and then the break before that will indicate the pre-covid period. So Im wondering since I want to divide my dataset in pre-covid and covid periods does it mean I should consider m=3? When I use m=3 compared to lets say m=5 I get different break points. The same happens when I extend my dataset from 2019-2022 to 2017-2022 for example.

Comment: The discovery of Covid and concerns about it both occurred *before* 01-03-2020, so why shouldn't the market show signs of a reaction?  Alternatively, plenty of other mechanisms exist to create breaks in the markets--why should they all be attributed to Covid??

Comment: The changepoints are trying to minimize the fit to the data.  You can get very different changepoints with m=3 and m=5 depending on the structure of the dataset.  Have you checked that the assumptions for the changepoint method you are using are approximately satisfied?  Inappropriate assumptions can often lead to wildly different, and "I wouldn't have put the changes there" results.  You could also use the changepoint.influence package to see the effect of the data on the changepoint segmentations.